# Should I put getDefaultSharedPreferences in application class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

As far as I know the `getDefaultSharedPreferences` is loading all the preference file into memory.
 In my app I have many classes where I pass the context and use `getDefaultSharedPreferences`. During the execution these classes load so many times, then as a result `getDefaultSharedPreferences` is called allot.
My question is: Should I load the preferences only one time in Application class and then access the preferences from there in all the classes? Is this doable? Will this increase the speed of my app? Anybody did this?

Something like this:

```
private static MyApplication singleton;

public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    return singleton;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    myPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}

public SharedPreferences getPreferences(){
    return myPreferences;
}
```

Comment: Ya you can do it. and as per my aspect it's increase speed and code readability.

Comment: This is called SingleTon pattern and you can initialize it anywhere, its not mandatory in the application class. My suggestion is, create a Helper class, initialize it in the Application class and use Helper.getPreference() method to get the instance.

Comment: @VishnuPrabhu Why you should create Helper singleton class. Application class itself singleton so used it.

Comment: @VishnuPrabhu That was actually my question: If I should use a helper class in Application class. I know that it can be initialized anywhere just don't want to initialize it allot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` caches after first load, so disk access to load data will take time but for only one time.Once they are in memory, after the first reference. The first time you retrieve a specific `SharedPreferences` (e.g., `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`), the data is loaded from disk, and kept around.

Comment: What if you close the activity. Will still be kept in memory for other activities?

Comment: If there is no need to put it in Application class then should I access it using Application context?

Comment: It depends on your memory size, if your is large enough to perform other operations then it will kept in memory otherwise it will be removed.
It is always better to use getApplicationContext()